# Создание файла .csv в opencv

Tags: opencv, c++

Я создаю файл .csv  в opencv. Внутри в столбиках по горизонтали коэффициент,  но когда получаю файл, результат не выводится. Есть у кого мысли по этому поводу?

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 void imhist(Mat image, int histogram[])
 {

// initialize all intensity values to 0
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    histogram[i] = 0;
}

// calculate the no of pixels for each intensity values
for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
        histogram[(int)image.at<uchar>(y,x)]++;

}
void histDisplay(int histogram[], const char* name)
{
    int hist[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        hist[i]=histogram[i];
    }
    // draw the histograms
    int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
    int bin_w = cvRound((double) hist_w/256);

    Mat histImage(hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    // find the maximum intensity element from histogram
    int max = hist[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 256; i++){
        if(max < hist[i]){
            max = hist[i];
        }
    }

    // normalize the histogram between 0 and histImage.rows

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        hist[i] = ((double)hist[i]/max)*histImage.rows;
    }

    // draw the intensity line for histogram
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        line(histImage, Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h),
                              Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h - hist[i]),
             Scalar(0,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    for (int iter = 1; iter <= 20; iter++) {
        ofstream myfile;
        char output_filename[100] = {0, };
        sprintf(output_filename, "D:/output_%d.csv", iter);
        myfile.open (output_filename);////////

        std::cout << "Open File: " << output_filename << std::endl;

        // from 128 to 224
        for (int tg_intname = 30; tg_intname <=31 ; tg_intname += 1) {
            for(int intname = 0; intname <= 256-(8*tg_intname);  intname++)/////////////
            {
                char name[100] = {0, };
                const int fn_tg_intname = 32 - tg_intname;
                sprintf(name, "D:/test%d/%d/img_%d.bmp", iter, fn_tg_intname, intname);///////

                std::cout << "Processing: " << name << std::endl;
                //cout <<name<<"-";
                //myfile<<name<<"  ";
                // Load the image
                // Mat image = imread("D:/Research/Research/test1/cropped_100.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
                Mat image = imread(name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

                // Generate the histogram
                int histogram[256];
                imhist(image, histogram);
                int ysum, tmpys, xsum, tmpxs;

                xsum=0;
                ysum=0;
                tmpxs=0;

                float AVG = 0, PixelSum = 0, NumberPixel = 0;

                for(int x = 0; x < image.rows; x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < image.cols; y++)
                    {
                        PixelSum += image.at<uchar>(x,y);
                    }

                    NumberPixel = image.rows*image.cols;

                    AVG = float(PixelSum / NumberPixel);
                    float Diff = 0;
                    for(int x = 0; x < image.rows; x++) {
                        for(int y = 0; y < image.cols; y++)
                        {

                            Diff +=  ((image.at<uchar>(x,y)/255) - (AVG/255)) * ((image.at<uchar>(x,y)/255) - (AVG/255));
                        }
                        float  RMS =0;
                        RMS = sqrt((1/(NumberPixel))* Diff);
                        // cout<<"- RMS  = "<<RMS<<endl ;
                        myfile << RMS << " ";
                    }
                }
            }
            myfile << std::endl;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо было выложить файл. Было бы ясно, почему он не открывается Excel-ем. Вопрос к opencv отношения не имеет. А Вы выложили некомпилируемый код генерации неизвестного файла, в котором какая-то ошибка :))